# Is this the correct way to test to see if two lines are colinear?

Tags: c++, class, codeblocks

My code in the colinear does not seem to work and its frustrating the hell out of me. Am i going the best way to use my line class by using two points in my point class?  My test for colinearlirty is crashing so I am stuck in a rut for the past few days.

```
bool line::isColinear(line)
{
     bool line2=false;
     line l1,l2;

     if (l1.slope()==l2.slope())
     {
         if (l1.y_int()==l2.y_int())
         {
             line2 =true;
             return line2;
         }
     }
     else
     { 
         line2 =false;
     }

}
```

//Heres a copy of my line class

```
class line
{
    private:

    point p1,p2;

    public:

    bool isColinear(line);
    bool isParallel(line);
    point solve(line);
    double slope();
    double y_int();
    void  Display(ostream&);
};
```

Comment: "Does not seem to work"? That doesn't give us much to go on. The function doesn't return anything of the lines are not colinear, so you're doing something wrong. Have you tested the other functions?

Comment: Did you run it through a debuger? It's helps you see where (and possibly why) it crashed.

Comment: This code is just wrong all over. Try writing a function that always returns `true`, get that to work, then build up. And accept an answer now and then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are storing line as between two points. Slope of a line is usually defined as

   `slope = (y2 - y1) / ( x2 - x1 )`

if **x1** is equal to **x2**, you can have a division by zero error/exception.

Other things to be careful about

1. If you are storing point coordinates as integers, you could be doing just a integer division and not get what you expect
2. If you are using doubles throughout, please use a tolerance when comparing them

Answer (score 1):

There's not nearly enough here to really judge what's going wrong, so a few generalities:

- Never compare floating-point values directly for equality. It won't work a surprising amount of the time. Instead, compare their difference with an amount so small that you're content to call it "zero" (normally we call it "epsilon"):

  ```
  if (abs((num1 - num2)) < 0.001) {
      /* pretend they're equal */
  } else {
      /* not equal */
  }
  ```
- `line2` is unnecessary in this example. You might as well return `true` or `false` directly from the conclusions. Often even the `return true` or `return false` is needlessly confusing. Lets assume you re-write this method a little to *three* methods. (Which might or might not be an improvement. Just assume it for a bit.)

  ```
  bool line::compare_slope(line l2) {
      return fabs((l2.slope() - self.slope()) < 0.001; // don't hardcode this
  }

  bool line::compare_origin(line l2) {
      return fabs((l2.y_int() - self.y_int()) < 0.001; // nor this
  }

  bool line::is_colinear(line l2) {
      return compare_slope(l2) && compare_origin(l2);
  }
  ```

  No `true` or `false` hard coded anywhere -- instead, you rely on the value of the conditionals to compute `true` or `false`. (And incidentally, the repetition in those functions goes to show that a function `floating_comparison(double f1, double f2, double epsilon)`, could make it far easier to modify epsilon either project-wide or compute an epsilon based on the absolute values of the floating point numbers in question.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that since `l1` and `l2` are uninitialized, their `slope` methods are doing a divide by zero. Initialize those properly or switch to the proper variables and you'll fix your crash.

Even once you get that working, the test is likely to fail. You can't compare floating point numbers and expect them to be equal, even if it seems they ought to be equal. You should read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

A simple formula for a line (in 2D) (derived from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form)) is:

P1(x1,y1) and P2(x2,y2) are the points determining the line.

> (y-y1) (x2-x1) + (y1-y2) (x-x1) = 0 ( let's use f(x,y) = 0 )

To test if two lines match imagine that a second line is defined by points P3(x3,y3), P4(x4,y4).

To make sure that those lines are 'quite' the same you should test if the two points (P3, P4) determining the second line are close 'enough' to the previous line.

This is easily done by computing f(x3,y3) and f(x4,y4). If those values are close to 0 then the lines are the same.

```
Pseudocode:
// I would chose tolerance around 1
if ( f(x3,y3) < tolerance && f(x4,y4) < tolerance )
{
    // line P1,P2 is the same as P3,P4
}
```